# Assigning locals to references to readonly fields (C# equivalent of "const &")

Tags: c#, reference, local-variables, c#-8.0, readonly-attribute

I've got a `struct` stored in a `readonly` field, nested in a few levels of objects (all in code that is outside of my control), that I am accessing in a function. For example:

```
struct Surprise { public readonly int a, b, c; }
struct Gizmo { public readonly Surprise surprise; }
struct Bobble { public readonly Gizmo gizmo; }
struct Thing { public readonly Bobble bobble; }
class Gift { public readonly Thing thing; }

void Function (Gift gift) {
    int contrived = gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.a +
                    gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.b + 
                    gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.c;
}
```

Purely to avoid having to type out `gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise` every time I use it, I'd like to assign that to a local variable with a shorter name. However, I also don't need to *copy* the struct, so I'd like to avoid that:

```
void Function (Gift gift) {
    
    { // (A) this is what i'm trying to not type out:
        int contrived = gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.a + 
                        gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.b +
                        gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.c;
    }
    
    { // (B) i can do this, but i don't *need* to copy, so i'd like to avoid:
        Surprise s = gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise;
        int contrived = s.a * s.b + s.c;
    }
    
    { // (C) what i *want* to do is something like this:
        ref Surprise s = ref gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise;
        int contrived = s.a * s.b + s.c;
    }
    
}
```

However, it seems that variation (C) there is not allowed, and so doesn't compile:

```
CS0192 A readonly field cannot be used as a ref or out value
  (except in a constructor)
```

My question is: **Is there a way to create a local variable that refers to a readonly value-typed field and doesn't copy it (or some other approach to save myself some typing)?**

I'm fairly new to C#, coming from C++. If you're familiar with C++ I'm essentially looking for the equivalent of:

```
const Surprise &s = gift->thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise;
```

Also: **Would it even make a difference, or is the compiler smart enough to not create a copy in (B) above?**

---

By the way, I did, after much struggle, come up with this nightmare:

```
delegate void Hack (in Surprise s);

void Function (Gift gift) {
    ((Hack)((in Surprise s) => {
        int contrived = s.a + s.b + s.c;
        ...;
    }))(gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise);
}
```

I'm not interested in that as an option, though, for hopefully obvious reasons. Also I'm not actually sure if that even avoids a copy.

Comment: You are 100% sure you need a struct?

Comment: @rene No, but I can't change it, so, in a way, yes. Edited to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

How about an extension method.

```
public static class GiftExtension
{
    public static int Sum(this Gift gift)
    {
        int contrived = gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.a +
                            gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.b +
                            gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.c;
        return contrived;
    }
    public static int Sum(this Surprise surprise)
    {
        int contrived = surprise.a +
                            surprise.b +
                            surprise.c;
        return contrived;
    }
}
```

then in your method, you can have

```
void Function(Gift gift)
    {
        {
            //(A)  was trying to use a pointer to access the memory location, couldn't get it to work!
            //unsafe
            //{
            //    Surprise* ps = &(gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise);
            //}
        }
        //(B)
        {
            int contrived = gift.Sum();
        }
        {
            int contrived = gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise.Sum();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Huh. That's not a bad idea, and it wouldn't be inappropriate in my actual application, either. Need some time to digest and decide if this is the best way.

Comment: Incidentally, re: your pointer comment, I was just going down the same path and ... also didn't get it working, lol (btw: check out keyword  `fixed`). I'm not sure it *can* be made to work because I found this hint [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#the-address-of-operator): *"...  outside an instance constructor or static constructor for a struct or class that defines a readonly field, that field is considered a value, not a variable. As such, its address cannot be taken."* -- So I think that approach is a dead-end.

Comment: Although that hint makes me wonder if simply doing `Surprise s = gift.....surprise` actually doesn't copy the data in the first place. Time to waste the rest of the day going down that rabbit hole, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Create a `readonly` property to access the value you want.

```
public struct Surprise
{
    get
    {
        return gift.thing.bobble.gizmo.surprise;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that copy it, though?

Comment: It is a `Struct` and therefore a value type. Any reference to it will create a copy. The only way out of that would be to use a ref return method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns